# Can't build click house query

Tags: database, clickhouse

I have a click house table like this:

```
page_id  ad_id   date  
-------|-------|------------|
1      | 10    | 04/03/2009 |
1      | 2     | 04/03/2009 |
1      | 2     | 04/03/2009 |
1      | 4     | 04/03/2009 |
1      | 2     | 04/03/2009 |
2      | 1     | 04/03/2009 |
2      | 5     | 04/03/2009 |
3      | 2     | 04/03/2009 |
3      | 2     | 04/03/2009 |
3      | 2     | 04/03/2009 |
3      | 8     | 04/03/2009 |
4      | 1     | 04/03/2009 |
4      | 1     | 04/03/2009 |
5      | 2     | 04/03/2009 |
```

This table contains the history of clicks on different ad-blocks on different pages. Just a big log. I want to get top ads with hits count for each page. Smthing like

```
page_id  ad_id   hits  
-------|-------|------------|
1      | 2     | 3          |
2      | 1     | 1          |
3      | 2     | 3          |
4      | 1     | 2          |
5      | 2     | 1          |
```

Hope somebody can help me. Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far and what DB are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT page_id, ad_id, count() cnt
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY page_id, ad_id
ORDER BY page_id, cnt DESC
LIMIT 1 BY page_id
```

[Link to doc](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/single/#limit-n-by-clause)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution with approximate calculations that can give an incompletely accurate result, but quickly (the number of hits can be counted through a subquery)

```
SELECT page_id, topK(1)(ad_id) ad_id
FROM table_name
GROUP BY page_id
```